# Reinstall Android Build Template from Project Menu

Tags: android, godot4

I had successfully exported the game in apk file. -- But along the way, I updated my Godot engine from 4.1.1 to 4.1.3. now, I am trying to export my game in Godot in an aab file. but an error occurred. what does this actually mean?
[image]

I am a little confused, is it telling me to reinstall it in Android Studio? or within Godot? Please Let me know.

I was expecting it to be exported smoothly as I did with apk.

Comment: nvm, it's within godot. 

delete the build template inside your game directory. and reinstall.

project settings> install android build template